# Firefox not forwarding to https://non-www.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, firefox, https, warnings

I am working on a GoDaddy VPS (Apache, CentOS, cPanel). I have an SSL certificate valid for `example.com` but NOT `www.example.com`.

I want to use a `.htaccess` file to forward any requests to `https://example.com/<pages>`.

My code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The problem:
All tested browsers (Chrome, Edge, Opera) work fine for all combinations of http, https, www, and specific pages. However, Firefox does NOT forward `https://www.example.com` (with or w/out pages).

I get a security warning stating that `www.example.com` is not on the cert.

I have tried numerous other code snippets but none seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox may seem like the oddball, but actually it's the other browsers doing it "wrong" - to be forgiving with other peoples' server misconfiguration in favor of the user's convenience. (Also, it will look less odd once you realize that all three browsers you mentioned - Chrome, Edge, Opera - are forks of Chromium.)

If you look in the Chrome devtools, you'll see this:

> Redirecting navigation `www.example.com` -> `example.com` because the server presented a certificate valid for example.com but not for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). To disable such redirects launch Chrome with the following flag: `--disable-features=SSLCommonNameMismatchHandling`

So, even though you didn't present a valid certificate for `https://www.example.com`, Chrome was nice enough to execute the redirect anyway, because you *did* present a certificate that was valid for the target domain of the redirect (`example.com`), even though technically the redirect response was returned over a connection that wasn't properly secured (with a certificate not matching the requested domain).

The solution would be to have a proper SSL certificate in the first place, including all the domains that you want your site to be reachable under, in that case probably just `example.com` and `www.example.com`. (Some certificate issuers will even include the `www` subdomain for free if you purchase a certificate for the naked domain.)

Comment: First: Thank you for the quick response.  
So, is it not proper to have a certificate with mapleriverfarms.com but not www.mapleriverfarms.com? Is there no way to coerce Firefox (and possibly others) to work around the www

Comment: No, the thing is that in order to establish a secure connection without a security warning, you need to present a certificate that matches the requested domain. Only then you can communicate over that connection, including getting the request contents sent to the server and responding with the redirect.

Comment: Great answer +1. Also note that the rule given in the question specifically targets HTTP only (`%{HTTPS} off`) so it won't match `https://www.example.com` anyway, even with a valid SSL certificate.